# What will a break-statement do in Axapta?

Tags: axapta, break, x++

I have 2 while loops, and in the second there is a break; (see the code below)

My question is: will the break cause a stop in the second loop or for the 2?

```
while select dirPartyRelationship
join    dirPartyTable
    where dirPartyTable.RecId == dirPartyRelationship.ChildParty
join    dirPersonName
    where   dirPersonName.Person == dirPartyTable.RecId
{
    while select checkDirRelationship
        where checkDirRelationship.ChildParty == dirPartyRelationship.RecId
    {
        if (checkDirRelationship.RelationshipTypeId == _relationshipType)
        {
            break;
        }
    }...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break will only break out of the current code block.

Create a job and use this sample code;

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<100; j++)
        {
            info(strfmt("inner loop count %1",j));
            break;
        }
        info(strfmt("outer loop count %1",i));
    }
```

You will see a quick example of j never getting over 0, but being printed 100 times.

**Edit;**

If you want to break out of the nested loop you could work around by declaring a `boolean`, maybe called `breakAll`, and setting `breakAll` to true before the `break;` line in the inner loop. In the outer loop check for `breakAll` like this;

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<100; j++)
        {
            info(strfmt("inner loop count %1",j));
            if (somethingToCheck)
            {
                breakAll = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        info(strfmt("outer loop count %1",i));
        if (breakAll)
        {
             break;
        }
    }
```